# requestMatcher(...).permitAll not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Im doing a basic auth using Spring security 6, but i dont understand why my permitAll() is not working. It keeps respone 401 unauthorize even when i tell it to permit that endpoint. This is my securityConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(request -> request.getRequestURI().contains("/register")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return new OurUserInfoUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;

    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity reg(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("HELOO");
    }
}
```

this is the debug console when i add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`

```
2024-03-24T00:52:24.232+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /register
2024-03-24T00:52:24.248+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /register
2024-03-24T00:52:24.282+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-03-24T00:52:24.296+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2024-03-24T00:52:24.297+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-03-24T00:52:24.304+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/error?continue to session
2024-03-24T00:52:24.314+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], And [Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@628bf7a9, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@628bf7a9, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@628bf7a9, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
2024-03-24T00:52:24.315+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@709090f8
2024-03-24T00:52:24.315+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2024-03-24T00:52:24.316+07:00 DEBUG 12296 --- [schoolManage] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@16b994d5
```

i have tried all method on same problem on stackoverflow but got no result, hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try requestMatchers() method:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
    .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
```

Comment: i just go for a similar question and changed from that code. Saddly, both doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
    .mvcMatchers("/register").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated())
```

This uses a more standard pattern matching and ensures that only requests exactly matching /register are permitted without authentication.

If it doesn't work, enable debug logging for Spring Security to get more insight into what's happening when you make a request to the `/register` endpoint. This can reveal something unexpected that you can get help with here.
You can enable debug logging by setting `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` in your application.properties or application.yml file.

Comment: i've debug as you recommended. It first secured the GET /register then it says securing GET /error. Im new in this field so i've got no idea what it means, but i think maybe the the /register is not permited as i intended.